Why does the order of matrix multiplication for transformation matrices seem reversed when transforming a point?
I'm working on a robotics/geometry problem where I use homogeneous transformation matrices to describe the position and orientation of a tool in 3D space. I compute the transformed position of a point $P$ using a sequence of transformation matrices $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n$.
From my understanding, the transformation order should work like this:

$T_1$ is the first transformation (e.g., global frame to frame 1).
$T_2$ is the second transformation (e.g., frame 1 to frame 2).
$T_n$ is the final transformation (e.g., frame $n-1$ to frame $n$).

When combining these transformations into a cumulative transformation matrix $T_{\text{total}}$, I would expect the correct order to be:
$$
T_{\text{total}} = T_n \cdot T_{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot T_1
$$
and then:
$$
P' = T_{\text{total}} \cdot P
$$
However, in my implementation, the multiplication is done in the opposite order:
$$
T_{\text{total}} = T_1 \cdot T_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot T_n
$$
and:
$$
P' = T_{\text{total}} \cdot P
$$
This approach $T_1 \cdot T_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot T_n \cdot P$ gives the correct result while $T_n \cdot T_{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot T_1 \cdot P$ does not which is unexpected.
Why does the cumulative transformation matrix computed in this "reversed" order work, while the sequential order does not?
Is there something about reference frames I am not understanding?
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
For context, I am trying to calculate the positional error of a robotic end effector due to angular misalignments between linkages. To achieve this, I use homogeneous transformation matrices to represent the rotation and translation between frames along a kinematic chain.
Here is the Python code I have written to do this:
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

# Function to create a homogeneous transformation matrix
def create_transformation(rotation_matrix, translation_vector):
    transformation = np.eye(4)
    transformation[:3, :3] = rotation_matrix
    transformation[:3, 3] = translation_vector
    return transformation

# Function to compute individual transformation matrices
def compute_transformation(misalignments, translation):
    rotation = R.from_euler('zyx', misalignments, degrees=True).as_matrix()
    return create_transformation(rotation, translation)

# Example transformations (representing linkages with misalignments and translations)
T1 = compute_transformation([1, 0, 0], [0, 200, 0])  # Base to end of linkage 1
T2 = compute_transformation([0, 1, 0], [300, 0, 0])  # end of linkage 1 to end of linkage 2
T3 = compute_transformation([0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 400])  # end of linkage 2 to end of linkage 3

# Cumulative transformation (expected to combine T3, T2, T1 correctly)
T_total = T3 @ T2 @ T1  # Matrix multiplication order

# Point to be transformed
P = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])  # Homogeneous coordinates

# Compute the transformed position
P_prime = T_total @ P

# Ideal transformation (assuming no misalignments)
T1_ideal = compute_transformation([0, 0, 0], [0, 200, 0])
T2_ideal = compute_transformation([0, 0, 0], [300, 0, 0])
T3_ideal = compute_transformation([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 400])
T_total_ideal = T3_ideal @ T2_ideal @ T1_ideal 

# Ideal position
P_prime_ideal = T_total_ideal @ P

# Calculate the positional error
error = P_prime[:3] - P_prime_ideal[:3]
error_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(error)

print("Transformed Position (P'):", P_prime[:3])
print("Ideal Position (P'_ideal):", P_prime_ideal[:3])
print("Positional Error:", error)
print("Error Magnitude:", error_magnitude)
``` 


Matrix multiplication is not commutative

I know it is not commutative however the issue I'm encountering is that using the seemingly incorrect order of matrix multiplication gives the correct result, while the expected correct order produces an incorrect result.

Yes the multiplication is in the expected correct order in the code as displayed. This order gives the incorrect result while T_total = T1 @ T2 @ T3 gives the correct result

Something that confuses is me is that if I read the code correctly the matrices that produce this phenomenon only have a translation part and no rotation part. But then it all becomes even more mysterious as pure transformation matrices should commute with eachother. Am I misinterpreting what is happening?

apology, I meant to type "pure translation matrices", not "pure tranformation matrices"

Perhaps in "transformation[:3, 3] = translation_vector" the second 3 should be a 4?

Your expected order works if you always work in the global coordinate frame. If you transform the coordinate frame itself, then the order is reversed. See also, intrinsic vs extrinsic Euler rotation.

Reading the question but not the code my guess was that it must be the thing that obareey describes. But then I tried to look in the code to see if I could see whether you move points around in a space described by a fixed coordinate frame, or keep the point fixed in one place in space and change the frame w.r.t. which you describe this space and  then I got confused about the things I mentioned above. Also I don't speak python very well so maybe that is in the source of my confusion
